# Can't set position of modal window

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite

I have a window I want to display as a modal window (OS X 10.10). I'm loading the NIB for the window and am able to set the title successfully and then display the window. But whatever I do to try to affect the window position doesn't work.

This works (part of NSWindowController sub-class):

```
[[self window] setTitle:title];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:[self window]];
```

Here are ways with which I've tried to affect the position after setting the title:

```
[[self window] setFrameOrigin: NSMakePoint(200.0, 200.0) ];
[[self window] setFrameTopLeftPoint: NSMakePoint(200.0, 200.0) ];
[[self window] setFrame: NSMakeRect(200, 300, [[self window] frame].size.width, [[self window] frame].size.height) display:YES];
```

(I've tried other values as well - just for testing, but nothing.)

I can even query the

```
[[self window] frame]
```

and it pretends to accept the new values, but the window stubbornly keeps showing up in the same position.

What gives?

Comment: In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/runModalForWindow:) they say "If it is not already visible, the window is centered on the screen using the value in its `center` method"

Comment: Sounds like a case of RTFD.... :) I had missed that little tidbit. I have now created a custom window class in which I overwrite the `center` method, which seems to successfully suppress the undesired behavior!

Comment: Could you please share some code regarding that?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by

1- Make a new NSWindow subclass, overriding the center method, where you just make the frame of the new window positioned at whatever NSPoint you want:

```
class CenteredInParentWindow: NSWindow {

    var parentMinX : CGFloat?
    var parentMinY : CGFloat?

    override func center() {
        guard let parentMinX = parentMinX, let parentMinY = parentMinY else {
            super.center()
            return
        }
        self.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: parentMinX, y: parentMinY))
    }
}
```

2 - Set WindowController's window class to be the new NSWindow subclass, in Storyboard.

3- Instatiate the window controller and set the attributes of the subclassed window

```
 let myWindowController = self.storyboard!.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "windowID") as! PlansWindowController
        if let customWindow = myWindowController.window as? CenteredInParentWindow {
            customWindow.parentMinX = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.frame.minX
            customWindow.parentMinY = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.frame.minY
        }
        NSApp.runModal(for: myWindowController.window!)
}
```

You may need `runModal` method for making the window a modal one. Don't forget to include `NSApp.stopModal()` in the `windowWillClose` method which is available in `NSWindowDelegate` in your View controller